# converting IP string to hex for dpkt.IP

Tags: python, string, hex

I want to learn packet decoder processing using dpkt. On the site, I saw the following example code:

```
>>> from dpkt.ip import IP                            
>>> ip = IP(src='\x01\x02\x03\x04', dst='\x05\x06\x07\x08', p=1)
>>> ...
```

How do I convert an IP String like `'1.2.3.4'` to `'\x01\x02\x03\x04'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`socket.inet_aton`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton):

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.inet_aton('1.2.3.4')
'\x01\x02\x03\x04'
```

To get the dotted decimal back, use [`socket.inet_ntoa`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_ntoa):

```
>>> socket.inet_ntoa('\x01\x02\x03\x04')
'1.2.3.4'
```

**UPDATE**

In Python 3.3+, [`ipaddress.IPv4Address`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address) is another option.

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.IPv4Address('1.2.3.4').packed
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'
>>> ipaddress.IPv4Address(b'\x01\x02\x03\x04')
IPv4Address('1.2.3.4')
>>> str(ipaddress.IPv4Address(b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'))
'1.2.3.4'
```

Comment: Think you meant `inet_ntoa` on the back to dotted decimal part.